# Embedding Google Charts dashboard in website

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-apps

I have created a Google Charts dashboard using Google Script and when I deploy it as a web app it works fine. I was wondering whether there is a way to embed the dashboard into a HTML page? I have tried using the HTML service instead of the UI service but instead of displaying the dashboard it just says "UIApplication". Below is the code for the dashboard and HTML page.

Dashboard in google script

```
function doGet() {

    return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
} 

function createDashboard() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Ar1JYhAF9RNsdENWZE9fdUw1ZlJwRENDRndlY3UzT2c'); 
 var sheet =  ss.getSheetByName('Charts');
 var data = sheet.getDataRange();

  var completeFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(0).build();

  var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
  .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0,1]))
  .build();

  var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
  .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0,1]))
  .setTitle('Number of completed tasks')
  .build();

  var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(data)
  .bind([completeFilter], [tableChart, pieChart])
  .build();

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var headerPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  headerPanel.add(app.createHTML("<center><h1>Welcome to the Charts Dashboard</h1></center>"));


  var filterPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var chartPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  filterPanel.add(completeFilter).setSpacing(10);
  chartPanel.add(tableChart).add(pieChart).setSpacing(10);

  dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel().add(headerPanel).add(filterPanel).add(chartPanel));
  app.add(dashboard);

  return app;  
}
```

HTML Page

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Google Charts Dashboard </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Welcome to the Charts Dashboard </h1>
<p>Hello, world! The charts are below: </p>
<p><? var data = createDashboard(); ?> </p>
<p> <?= data ?> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working or if it is possible? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that the simplest way to do this is to use an iFrame.  You can find details about iFrames here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Basically, you will need the URL of your webapp and put it in the iFrame like this (replace the URL shown with the one from your webapp):

This would go in your HTML wherever you want to display the dashboard.  There are several options for setting height, width, etc, so experiment with it.

(Note: since you're talking about forming HTML, I'm assuming this is not a g-sites page you're using, but if it is, you can't manually insert iFrames using HTML in g-sites.  There is, however, an iFrame gadget you can use.  Go to insert Gadgets and choose More Gadgets...search for iFrame and you should find it.  Once you embed the gadget, there's a place in the gadget's settings for putting the URL of your gadget)

Comment: i already tried that and it doesn't work, it might be because when I deploy it as a web app, it only lets me share it within the company domain.

Comment: I tried copying it to another another Google account and set it to allow anyone, even anonymous, and then used that link but it still didn't work